# Не выходить за радиус Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли возможность в Unity 5 чтобы движущееся тело не выходило из некого радиуса? В Unity 3D это просто, там стены нормальные, а в Unity 2D стены откровенно дырявые, иногда пробивает их. Может есть что то типо поводка, привязанного к определённой точке и дальше этого поводка тело уйти не может?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вопрос состоит только в радиусе, вы можете в условиях к движению(обработках кнопок) 
прописать, что-то, вроде двигаться, если `R < Math.sqrt(x^2+y^2)`, где `R` ваш радиус до объекта.

Comment: эммм съело половину сообщения.... если R<Math.sqrt(x^2+y^2)
где R радиус до объекта

Comment: Это хорошо конечно, а если оно уже вышло за радиус? С разгона, например. Приведите пожалуйста пример более точно. Там нет кнопок, там просто полет по случайным координатам.

Если быть более точным, то сначала мы меняем угол игрока, потом по этому углу Vector2.up. Угол формируется случайным образом. Это происходит каждые 2-3 секунды,оно летит и меняет направление движение. Как такое ограничить?

Comment: а следующая координата есть по этому вектору? Прежде чем передвигать на неё игрока, проверьте, не вышло-ли оно за рамки. Если вектор, то возможно проверка будет "координатаХ+векторХ<R" и так-же по Y.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю что у вас неправильная техника реализации передвижения обьекта (например реализовано через изменение трансформ.позишн) и как следствие - прохождение сквозь коллайдер

Или же как-то криво настроенные коллайдеры или их взаимодействие. Там есть настройка просчета точности взаимодействия между коллайдерами, можно попробовать поставить выше точность. ( поправьте в свойствах Rigidbody поля Interpolate и Collision Detection)